# R tries to read CSV files from the folder where the code is instead of the indicated by the code

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, read.csv

I use the `here` package in tandem with an R project. `Tidyverse` is also used.

There are three relevant folders in the R Project folder - the "Code" folder that contains the different R Markdown files, the "Data" folder that contains unaltered CSV files, and the "Final Files" folder into which I hope export the final files from R. I'll refer to the "R Project folder" as the base directory folder; the other three folders (Code, Data, and Final Files) reside in this base directory folder.

The problem is this. When I run the code to load in the csv files, the following message shows up.

```
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! 'filename.csv' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/.../base directory folder - R Project/Code').
```

Here is my code that leads to this message:

```
years = 2011:2021

data_folder = here::here("Data") 
  
file_names = dir(data_folder, pattern = "*.csv")

file_names = file_names[grepl(paste(years, collapse = "|"), file_names)] %>% 
  paste0("Data/", .)

data_list = file_names %>% 
  map(read_csv)
```

This is weird because when I run either the command `here::here()` or `getwd()`, the base directory folder is returned. Yet, when I run the code to load in the data, R seems to attempt obtaining the data from the "Code" folder.

When I move the R Markdown file from the Code folder to the base directory folder, R then successfully loads in the data. This leads me to believe that R is seemingly deeming the folder that the R Markdown file is in to be the directory when I load the data.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Is this code included in a Markdown file?  Markdown files are not necessarily knitted in the project's root folder.  So, put a `getwd()` in the Markdown file to see where it is being executed and adjust your paths accordingly.  Also, `file.path()` is a better solution than `paste0` because it is independent of OS.

Comment: It uses a heuristic which depends on which other files are present so it is difficult to diagnose without reviewing all the files you have.  Read `?here` carefully and try to relate it to your situation.  If that does not help try the `this.path` package or just use paths relative to the current directory without any such package or define the base directory in an option in your .Rprofile.  e.g. `options(xyz = "C:/xyz")` and use that. I find the last one particularly helpful since I can forget where I put things and if I do I can just look in the .Rprofile file.

Comment: Does it help to use `dir(..., full.names=TRUE)`?